# How to keep LESS variables in CSS file?

Tags: css, less

I created a LESS file and put in some variables for color definitions:

```
@white:     #fff;
@black:     #000;
```

When the CSS file was generated I lost all variables, and now I can't use less.modifyVars because the CSS file doesn't have any LESS variables.

How can I keep LESS variables when CSS is automatically saved?

Comment: CSS doesn't 'understand' that. You can keep the less files, but the generated CSS will not include the variables.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'variables' in CSS

Answer (score 2):

LESS parses to CSS. So the variables are being replaced by their values wherever you use them in your LESS. Your 'autosave' functionality should always parse the LESS to CSS and it's the CSS file you include in your project.

To be complete (from my comment): "less.modifyVars is a helper method which you can use to change some variables on the fly **BEFORE** the CSS is generated."

Comment: i know that... but is there any chance to avoid that and keep the variables in generated css..tnx

Comment: @MarkoS What would you do with them if they were available? Changing them wouldn't change the generated CSS.

Comment: @MarkoS Well no. Like you said, CSS does not contain the variables. That is simply because it doesn't understand them.

Comment: well i would like to use less.modifyVars (because only recognize less variables) and then change some color with jquery events etc.

Comment: less.modifyVars is a helper method which you can use to change some variables on the fly BEFORE the CSS is generated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding how `modifyVars` can be used. This is an example I found:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="theme-1488.less">
<script src="less-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        less.modifyVars({'@SCREEN_BODY_WIDTH' : '50px'});
</script>
```

Note that the *.less* file is included on the page, not the *.css* file.

Comment: Yes, the `.modifyVars` can only be used "on the fly" if one is compiling client side (as this example does) rather than server side. Of course, it is often strongly recommended not to do that for performance purposes, but it is possible.